# How to populate textbox with data , using selected combobox items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combobox.items.add=("peter magdy");

    if (combobox.selecteditems=("peter magdy")
    textbox.text==("age 23, male, etc");
}
```

this code helps you to populate textbox with value from combobox

Comment: that's some interesting syntax

Comment: why brackets `(` and `)`? from where did you get reference of such syntax?

Comment: i need to get the right code please

Comment: @user2975231 what problem are you facing. Just describe it here

Comment: i want to when i select an item from combobox , populate textbox with data , like dictionary idea ,

Comment: @user2975231 try out my answer if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

Consider this

```
// your person model where you hold person info
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
    public string Sex {get; set;}
}

// You will hold not strings but real objects in combo
private void LoadCombo()
{
    var john = new Pesron(){Id = 0, Name = "John", Age = 20, sex = "Male"};
    var maria = new Pesron(){Id = 1, Name = "Maria", Age = 19, sex = "Female"};
    var couple = new []{john, maria};

    combobox.DataSourse = couple;
    combobox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    combobox.ValueMember = "Id";
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Then you can have entire person information at your disposal
    var p = (Person)combobox.SelectedItem;

    textbox.text = string.Format("Name {0}, Age {1}", p.Name, p.Age);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add("peter magdy");

    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "peter magdy")
        textBox.Text = "age 23, male, etc";
}
```

Maybe you will have to change names of components (in code or in the winform designer), though.

Answer (score 0):

Textbox have `Text` property which can set/get text.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combobox.items.add=("peter magdy");

    if (combobox.selecteditems=("peter magdy")
        textbox.Text ="age 23, male, etc";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also seeing for SelectionChangeComitted event in place of selectionIndexChange.

SelectionChangeComitted is a last event of the selection which should be the place just before the value is set to comboBox.

SelectedIndex change may not come when when you use up and down arrows in comboBox but the text of comboBox still changes.